# click event for x-axis labels for amstock chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I'm developing a sample application using amstock chart with the [reference URL](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/stock-events/).

So I thought of adding a click event for X axis labels. I've googled about adding a click event and found nothing. ( I tried inspecting elements and adding click events using jquery but when I'm resizing, the click events are not working ).

Is the amstock chart itself not supporting any click event on the graph(on x-axis lables) or did I miss something?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

AmStock does support the [`clickItem`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxis#clickItem) event.
For stock charts you have to add it to each panel you want the event to be listened for. (Each panel has its own categoryAxis)
Example code:

```
chart.addListener("init", function() {
    for (i = 0; i < chart.panels.length; i++) {
        chart.panels[i].categoryAxis.addListener("clickItem", function(e) {
            // do something
        });
    }
});
```

A wild [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6rc8y00/) appeared!